# Wildly different query performance on similar tables?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select duplicate rows from a series of MySQL tables. The following query...

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name
IN (SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT column_name
          FROM table_name
          GROUP BY column_name
          HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
          ) AS subquery)
);
```

...is producing wildly different performance when run in different tables with identical schema and similar number of rows. In one table it executes within a few seconds, in another with identical data types and similar number of rows it is hanging up for an extended period of time (currently at 30 minutes and counting). What possible explanations are there for such a discrepancy?

EDIT - using EXPLAIN is showing that all the queries are returning "Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables" for the dependent subquery. This probably is a good time to mention that there are no indexes on any of the tables (which I inherited...). Finding duplicate values in what is supposed to be a `uniqid` column so that I can turn that into a proper primary key is the point of this entire snape hunt.

Comment: different db engines (myisam vs innodb or another) and different indexes are the first things that come to mind. What is the output from `EXPLAIN SELECT * ....` for each of them?

Comment: that your tables are different. That mysql is upset at correlated subqueries and is doing a sit down strike. Who knows

Comment: And I don't know if it would make a difference, but you could try `SELECT * FROM table_name AS query JOIN (subquery...) AS subquery ON subquery.column_name LIKE query.column_name;`

Comment: how about exploring indexes in place, @Jakar

Comment: @Jakar, posted output from EXPLAIN

Comment: If this is a one-time operation, why don't you just build some tables to help you with the process? You can start by doing a `SELECT DISTINCT (uniqid) FROM ...` to populate a new table of distinct unique id's and then use the table to join to your existing tables to select out data for insert into the permanent tables.

Comment: Why do you have the `SELECT *` wrapper query? Why not just `WHERE column_name IN (SELECT column_name FROM ...)`?

Comment: `EXPLAIN` tells you what MySQL wants to do. The table type tells you how the entire system will behave finding your data - InnoDB is efficient doing so by using RAM to handle the data, MyISAM is optimized in sequential disk writing and seeking. What you're doing is going through entire data set in an inefficient manner (no indexes as you said). Some queries have impossible where which equals to no rows - it's quick, nothing's done. Bottom line - MySQL is slow in retrieving data from your hard drive. That's why the query which yields results is slow and one with impossible where isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest splitting the subquery out into a temporary table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DupeColumn AS (
    SELECT column_name
        FROM table_name
        GROUP BY column_name
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);

SELECT t.*
    FROM DupeColumn dc
        INNER JOIN table_name t
            ON dc.column_name = t.column_name;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE DupeColumn;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, MySQL is very poor at optimizing

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE col1 in (SELECT col2 FROM table2 WHERE ...)
```

Instead of performing the subquery once and then looking up all the `col2` values in `table1`, it performs a full scan of `table1` and then searches for `col1` in `table2.col2`.

It does better when you write a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.col1 = table2.col2
```

In your case, this would be done using a subquery for `table2`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table_name AS t1
JOIN (SELECT column_name
      FROM table_name
      GROUP BY column_name
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS t2
ON t1.column_name = t2.column_name
```